# Change the direction of the switch

Tags: java, android

How can I change the direction of the switch modes in Android? That is the situation off will be on the right and on the situation will be on the left?

Comment: When using right to left layout.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the [`textOff` / `textOn`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html#attr_android:textOff) attributes so that the "Off" side says "On" and vice versa. Using various style attributes, you can tweak the colors too.

Just **don't forget to invert the value of `isChecked` in your `OnCheckedChangeListener`**.

Comment: What did you try, and what happened?